# ES file explorer is showing my Android phone's internal storage as SD Card

Tags: es-file-explorer

It's been a year since I've started using ES file explorer. It was working fine before. But after some update it started showing my phone's internal storage as SD card storage and SD card as phone memory. I'm continuously updating the app. Reinstalled it some times. But the issue is always present with every update. It's too annoying.The screenshot that I've added here shows the issue. I'm using a 16 GB memory card and ES explorer is showing it as internal storage. How can I fix this issue?[image: The screenshot that I've added here shows the issue. I'm using a 16 GB memory card and ES explorer is showing it as internal storage.]

Comment: I have a device with only one internal storage that has the same problem. Everything besides the system thinks the external SD card is the internal storage.

Comment: This is just a naming issue. AFAIK Google gives no clear directions how to name the mount points of the internal "sdcard" section and the external sd-card. Therefore every manufacturer makes it a little bit different. Therefore it is not easy for an app to identify what is what.